# Simplifying $ \;x({y^{3}}/{x^{4}})^{1/4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I’m a little unsure how to simplify the following expression:
$$
x\left(\frac{y^{3}}{x^{4}}\right)^{1/4}
$$

According to the answer, this should get you $\;\; x y^{3/4} x^{-1} = y^{3/4} $.

My intuition tells me that when we bring up $ \,x^{4} \,$ from the denominator, we get $ \,x^{-4}\, $ (with a negative power). In general, I’m unsure how $ x $ on the outside should multiply with what is inside the brackets. (Following [BEDMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), brackets should go first, right?)

Comment: Please use LaTeX formatting next time.

Comment: I would also suggest using \frac instead of /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$ x\Bigl(\frac{y^3}{x^4}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
You can leave out the braces, if you apply the exponent $\frac14$ to each, nominator and denominator. Thus
$$ x\Bigl(\frac{y^3}{x^4}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{4}}=x\frac{y^\frac{3}{4}}{x^1}$$
Now as $\frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$ you get
$$ x\Bigl(\frac{y^3}{x^4}\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{4}}=x{y^\frac{3}{4}}{x^{-1}}=x^{1-1} y^\frac34= y^\frac34$$

Comment: x^1/4*X^4 should be x(^1)? if I'm reading that right ? if so this solution is more elegant.

Comment: No $x^\frac14 \cdot x^4 = x^{\frac14+4}=x^\frac{17}{4}$. But $\bigl(x^\frac14 \bigr)^{4} = x^{\frac14\cdot 4} = x^1 = x$.

Comment: good solution anyway. thanks, this is much more straightforward.

Comment: I wouldn't say, that my solution is better than the one of @amWhy. Note, that he is more detailed and really takes his time with his comments.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align} 
x\left(\frac{y^3}{x^4}\right)^{1/4}  \\ \\
& = x(y^3x^{-4})^{1/4} \\ \\
& = xy^{3(1/4)}x^{-4(1/4)} \\ \\
& = xy^{3/4}x^{-1} \\ \\
& = xx^{-1}y^{3/4} \\ \\
& = \frac xx (y^{3/4}) \\ \\
& = y^{3/4} \\ \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: so the y^3 multiplies with ^-4 to give you 3/4? What about the remaining X on the outside or the ^1\4 power ?

Comment: No, the $y^3$ becomes $y^{3(1/4)} = y^{3/4}$ and $x^{-4}$ becomes $x^{-4(1/4)} = x^{-1}$ I edited to make this clearer to you.

Comment: Does that make sense now? You distribute the exponent $1/4$ over $y^3x^{-4}$

Comment: can anyone explain why you can gather powers like in step 2? Is it because of commutivity ? (sorry laggy internet on this one)

Comment: Do you mean placing x next to $x^{−1}$? Yes, multiplication is commutative, so you can rearrange/commute factors. ...Perhaps you mean why $(y^3x^{-4})^{1/4} = y^{3/4}x^{-4/4} = y^{3/4}x^{-1}\,$? Because one of the laws of exponents is $(ab)^c = a^cb^c$. So $(a^db^e)^c = a^{c \cdot d}b^{c\cdot e}$

Comment: I meant the latter -  why is c not applicable to all terms? a^{d*c}*b^{c*e}?

Comment: It is applicable to all terms: as I wrote: $$(a^db^e)^c = a^{cd}b^{ce} = a^{dc}b^{ce}$$

Comment: So $$(y^3x^{-4})^{1/4} = y^{3(1/4)}x^{-4(1/4)} = y^{3/4}x^{-1}$$ The scope of the exponent $1/4$ is all and only the factors in parentheses. So we multiply $y^{3/4}x^{-1}\;$ by $x:\quad$ $x(y^{3/4}x^{-1}) = xy^{3/4}x^{-1} = x x^{-1}y^{3/4} = \dfrac xx y^{3/4} = y^{3/4}$

Comment: makes sense thank you :)